# configure question: What would be the most appropriate place to install example programs for a library?

Tags: makefile, installation, configure

I'm currently writing a configure script for a library and would like to package it with some sample binaries to give examples on how to use it. Where would be the most appropriate location to install these binaries when a user runs "make install"? I ask what would be appropriate in terms of what would comply with GNU standards.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `/your_prefix_installation_path/share/your_package_name` folder to do it. Which is the general folder to put the documentation/example in.

To do it:

For instance, the following snippet how to install your file into ‘$(datadir)/your_package_name’.

```
 yourexampledir = $(datadir)/your_package_name/
 yourexample_DATA = your file here
```

Answer (score 0):

In an "Examples" folder, off the installation directory.

If the installation folder for the library is a "System" folder, make an installation directory in the usual "My Programs" place, and put instructions in the README on how to find it.

Comment: Would this comply with the GNU standards?